# SQLAlchemy - Session.commit in Session.query loop resets object __dict__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When iterating over `session.Query` object and calling update, I've noticed that the returned objects no longer have their `__dict__`'s populated.

E.g.

```
foos = session.query(Foo)
for foo in foos:
    print "{}".format(foo.__dict__)
    foo.somefield = "somevalue"
    session.add(foo)
    session.commit()  # The next print statement won't show anything
```

If any of the fields in `foo` are read during the iteration, though, all of the `__dict__` fields become resolved.

E.g.

```
foos = session.query(Foo)
for foo in foos:
    # Reading any of the fields, causes all of the fields to be resolved.
    foo.somefield
    print "{}".format(foo.__dict__)
    foo.somefield = "somevalue"
    session.add(foo)
    session.commit()  # The next print statement won't show anything
```

Is there any way to have these values appear in `__dict__` without needing to read them first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is that SQLAlchemy automatically expires your instances after you call `commit()`. So what happens in order:

1. you load all `Foo`s
2. print `__dict__`, works
3. commit
4. all `Foo`s are expired (empties the `__dict__` of all `Foo`s)
5. print `__dict__`, empty, oops

Reading a field will lazily re-load the instance from the database which is why that works. What you want to do is to turn off [expire_on_commit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker.params.expire_on_commit), e.g. if you use `sessionmaker`:

```
Session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False)
```

But be careful that naïve code may no longer do what you expect.

Comment: Ah okay. Do you have an example of a gotcha/edge case that might break from setting the flag to false?

Comment: @funseiki The problems that arise are not really edge cases, but basically you can't assume that the state loaded in your instance is up to date. You just have to keep in mind that you may be working with stale data, and that database transaction semantics may not be able to save you.

Comment: So in my example, when the attribute was read, was there another query occurring that would fetch the latest data from the database? If I turn off expire_on_commits, does that mean a cursor is not being used (as in, are all rows returned at once)?

Comment: @funseiki Yes -- a query is executed in every loop. All rows are by default fetched from the database all at once anyway, without streaming the results, regardless of whether you use `expire_on_commit` or not (this happens when you iterate over `foos`, i.e. `for foo in foos`), so those queries that occur on attribute access are unnecessary.